How can I use Debezium Server to monitor a PosgresSQL db and save the changes to a json file?
I have a docker compose with a postgres, debezium server, and wanted to find a way to locally store the changes in a json file. Have been searching, but didn't find any promising directions.
I connected to postgres using debezium connec and kafka, but I also don't know how to export the change data to a json file.
Any tips?
